# pandas for loop too slow

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am now busy with analyzing CSV datalog files and I am now strugling with how to speed up some pandas calculations. The following for loop is working but is not very fast:

```
for i in range(len(df)):

    if i==0:
        df.loc[i,"delta_t"] = 3
        df.loc[i,"E_sun"] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[i,"delta_t"] = (df.loc[i,"date_time"]- df.loc[i-1,"date_time"]).total_seconds()
        df.loc[i,"E_sun"] = df.loc[i-1,"E_sun"] + df.loc[i,"delta_t"] * df.loc[i,"E_flow_sun"]
```

Is there a fast way to do this calculation? The problem is that I am referencing information on different rows. If all the data is on the same row than things become very easy for example:

```
df["column1"] = df["column2"] + df["column3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
df['delta_t'] = df['date_time'].diff().total_seconds().fillna(3)

df['E_sun'] = (df['delta_t'] * df['E_flow_sun']).cumsum()
```